# Lightning iframe URL with & sign

Tags: lightning, string

I just want to create a simple iframe:

```
<aura:application implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

<iframe src="https://myURL.com/views/S28/ALL?:embed=y&:showShareOptions=true&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no&:toolbar=top" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"  height="4000"/>

</aura:application>
```

But I am getting an error:

> Failed to save undefined: 0Ad0Y000001EUo9:3,101: ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[4,101] Message: The reference to entity ":showShareOptions"
>   must end with the ';' delimiter.: Source

I tried adding `\` before `&` and `:` but it is not working. Also tried to find the answer online but so far no luck.

Comment: If you use the encoded value of `&amp;` does this get properly decoded by the framework at runtime?

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Set this as the answer and I will give you the credit.